# Extract Emails from Distribution List

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I have an email that is a distribution list. This email forwards messages to all users that are in this distribution list. Is there a way to extract these contacts via Google Apps Script?

I know that via Google Apps Script you can extract contacts within a group as follows:

```
var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('My Group');
var contacts = group.getContacts();
```

However, the distribution list is a contact and not a group.
My distribution list in this case is :

```
dl-a-few-contacts@mydomain.de
```

I have tried the **getContactsByName** and **getContactsByEmail** methods, however I only get the info about the distribution email there , not about the email address this distribution email forwards to.

Comment: Is the distribution list a google group? Or is the distribution list managed by a particular user? Can you say a bit more about how the list is managed?

Comment: Have you tried  `ContactApp.getContactById().getAddresses();` that's an array of all email addresses for that contact.  If you don't understand that you should spend more time in the documention.  Or I suppose it could be that you are using you contact in a way in which it wasn't intended and in the case you need to provide that information as part of your [mcve]